# Why is there an upper limit to tab completion's "display all 3197 possibilities?"

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a directory containing many (.pdb) files--9917 of them.  I wanted to count them to make sure that they were all there (the download said there would be 9917).  When I cd into the directory and then hit tab twice the terminal responds:

```
Display all 3197 possibilities? (y or no)
```

I at first thought there was an error with the download, but when I tried:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

I saw that all 9917 files were indeed there.  My question is: why the upper limit of 3197?  It doesn't seem to me that this number is anything particularly special.  It is not the largest signed integer (short, int, or long)--in fact it requires 12 bits to store (not all 1's).  If that maximum value is something that is relatively easily changed (some setting somewhere) I'd also be curious to know how to change it.

If it matters, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (but I suspect this is not a Ubuntu issue, although I suppose it is possible that the max value changes from system to system).  Also, the shell I am using is bash.

Comment: It is not listing the number of files in your dir. `3197` is the number of executable in your `PATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press Tab in your terminal with no other arguments, you're completing entries from your path, not the current directory. If you want to do that, try prepending another argument.

If you look at the output of bash's `compgen -c` (which will list all executables in your `$PATH`), you should see it more closely matches your expectations:

```
compgen -c | wc -l
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  The ./ didn't work for me (because none of the files are executable), but when I used vi <tab> <tab> it offered to list all 9917 files.